# How to use C# static string with Nlua

Tags: c#, lua, nlua

I am using NLua for script interface with my application.
I want to send keyboard input from LUA language to my C# code.

I do with this C# code.

```
   using (Lua lua = new Lua())
   {
      lua.LoadCLRPackage();

      lua.RegisterFunction("keypressC", null, typeof(TestNLUA).GetMethod("keypressC"));
      lua.RegisterFunction("keypressS", null, typeof(TestNLUA).GetMethod("keypressS"));

      lua["Key"] = new SpecialKey();
   }

    public class SpecialKey
    {
        public static readonly char EnterC = '\uE007'; 
        public static readonly string EnterS = Convert.ToString(EnterC);
    }

   public class TestNLUA
   {
      public static void keypressC(char key)
      {
         // key = 57351 => OK
      }

      public static void keypressS(string key)
      {
         char[] akey = key.ToCharArray();
         // akey[0] = 63 = ? (question mark) => KO
      }
   }
```

And in LUA Script I do

```
keypressC(Key.EnterC)
keypressS(Key.EnterS)
```

In keypressC, Nlua passe value 57351 to key parameter. It's OK.

In keypressS, Nlua passe value "?" to key parameter. It's KO. 
I have no idea why there is the character "?". 
Looks like a marshaling error in NLua (i.e. LuaInterface)?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a marshaling problem in nLua/LuaInterface.

It uses `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi` to marshal a string from C# to Lua.
It uses `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to marshal a string from Lua to C#.

If you round-trip your example string through these functions, you can see it reproduces your problem:

```
 string test = "\uE007";

 Console.WriteLine(test);
 Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", test[0], (int) test[0]);

 IntPtr ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(test);
 string roundTripped = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr, test.Length);

 Console.WriteLine(roundTripped);
 Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", roundTripped[0], (int) roundTripped[0]);
```

Output:

```
?
?: 57351
?
?: 63
```

Your problem goes away if you change the the marshaling functions to use `Uni` instead of `Ansi`, but you'd need to build nLua/LuaInterface from source.

Comment: Because of this marshaling problem in nLua/LuaInterface, I test **[NeoLua](https://neolua.codeplex.com/)**, Lua for .net dynamic language runtime.   In effect **NeoLua** uses the .NET string, and you can use all the functionality e.g. `'    test   ':Trim()`

Comment: I tried NeoLua, but it was too buggy. For instance, even the ["simple example" on their documentation page](http://neolua.codeplex.com/documentation) crashes.

Comment: I didn't have problems.  Opens a discussion on [codeplex](https://neolua.codeplex.com/discussions), NeoLithos responds quickly.

Comment: Fixed in NLua, will be in NuGet soon https://github.com/NLua/NLua/commit/1523aa966f1de118f34ab99a935abb463c537705